# Regex for curly braces

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need create a regex which does not allow any opening or closing curly bracket repeating ({{ or }} or {abc{ or abc}def}) one after the other with or without string/text between them .
Eg:

```
 abc123{xyz345}abc1234 - allowed,
 abc1 23 { xyz345 } abc1234 - allowed(with spaces),
 abc34{{jkljkl}}hkh- not allowed,
 abc34 { { jkljkl } } hkh- not allowed,
 abc34{fgf123{jkljkl}fgfg} hkh- not allowed
```

Comment: this regex `{(?=.*{).*}` does not allow

Comment: Thanks. It covered abc{hgjhgj{} string also. But skipped unclosed ones. eg: aacc{notclosed{

Comment: i included them see answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, it matches "not allowed"

```
{(?=.*{).*}?
```

[Try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/TUKbU8/1/)

Comment: I am new to regex, so could you please tell me how could I use it in ng-pattern in angularJS. Actually I want a regex in ng-pattern which will allow anything but not the above "not allowed" strings.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `{.*{.*}.*}` can detect all of the disallowed strings in your example - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/5)